# How to find $f(15/2)$ if $f(x+1)=f(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose $f(x+1)=f(x)$ for all real $x$. If $f$ is a polynomial and $f(5)=11$, then $f(15/2)$ is ??

How do I approach questions like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that how a polynomial can be periodic! Is there any other way than being a **constant**? So your function is really $f(x)=11$. That's all.

Comment: You call this a proof? :)

Comment: Nope! :) It's is called intuition! My understanding from OP question was that   OP just needs a simple intuition rather than a proof in analysis. :) See the tags **algebra** and **pre-calculus**.

Comment: That's a simple probability that anyone could mention, Martini's hint was a good elementary intuition.

Comment: @H.R. I feel like your answer very much reproduces that by martini :-)

Answer (score 9):

**Hint**. If $f$ is a non-constant polynomial, what can you say about $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$? Can $f$ be periodic in that case?

Answer (score 6):

Using the binomial theorem,
$$
(x+1)^n-x^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}x^k\tag{1}
$$
That is, $(x+1)^n-x^n$ is a degree $n-1$ polynomial whose lead term is $nx^{n-1}$.

Suppose that
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_kx^k\tag{2}
$$
where $a_n\ne0$ and $n\ge1$. Then
$$
f(x+1)-f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k\left[(x+1)^k-x^k\right]\tag{3}
$$
The terms with $k\lt n$ yield polynomials with degree at most $n-2$. The term with $k=n$ produces a polynomial with lead term $na_nx^{n-1}$.

Since $f(x+1)-f(x)=0$, all of its coefficients must be $0$. In particular the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ is $0$. However, this contradicts the assumption that $a_n\ne0$. Therefore, $n=0$.

That is, $f(x)$ is constant.